# preg_match_all match whole sentences

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am trying to get the whole sentence:

`PRICE CHANGE this this : this var1 : this/this (this) var2,var3 : 111,11 Price(€)   : 1.021 start from : 2012-07-26 18:15:00`

From:

`timezone. PRICE CHANGE this : this var1 : this/this(this) var2, var3 : 119, 111 Price(€)    : 5.021 start from : 2012-07-26 18:15:00 PRICE CHANGE this : this  this2 var1 : this  (this ) var2, var3 : 1604, 452 Price(€)   : 6.014 start from : 2012-07-26 18:15:00 bla bla bla bla.`

Using this:

```
body = "timezone. PRICE CHANGE this : this var1 : this/this(this) var2, var3 : 119, 111 Price(€)     : 5.021 start from : 2012-07-26 18:15:00 PRICE CHANGE this : this  this2 var1 : this  (this ) var2, var3 : 1604, 452 Price(€)   : 6.014 start from : 2012-07-26 18:15:00 bla bla bla bla."

$test = preg_match_all('/PRICE CHANGE\s*(.*?)*(\d+:\d+:\d+)', $body, $result);
```

And it's not working, help?

Comment: You're missing your last / and (.*?)* doesn't make sense, also I'm not sure whether " . " will match a " € ", try '/PRICE CHANGE\s+([\s\S]*?)(\d+:\d+:\d+)/gi'

Comment: nevermind, solved it using $test = `preg_match_all('/PRICE CHANGE\s*(\s+\S+\D+\w+\W+)*(\d+:\d+:\d+)/', $body, $result);` thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/PRICE CHANGE.*?(?=PRICE CHANGE)/', $body, $result);
```

Will do the trick, unless there's something you're not telling us about the structure.  If it really is just a list of price changes, this'll do the tric and be much more readable.

The '(?=' In case you didn't know, is a lookahead.  It's a zero width (matches no characters) assertion that checks the upcoming characters.  When combined with a lazy operator, it can be a great way to break up strings.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood, you want to catch the time from each change, right? To do it, you can change your expression this way:

```
'/PRICE CHANGE\s*(.*?)(\d+:\d+:\d+)/i'
```

Maybe the `i` modifier isn't completely necessary.